# change appearance of related views depending on which view was clicked, without a big long switch statement

Tags: android, view

I have an app that has a lot of buttons, and when a button is clicked, it plays a corresponding sound depending on which button was clicked.

I'm doing this by using the name of the button that was clicked to get the internal android resource ID of the sound file with the same name, and playing that sound, all in one method, and eliminating the need to test which button was clicked with a big long switch statement.

Now I want to do something similar to change the appearance of related views (ie. not the button that was clicked but 2 other views related to which button was clicked, once again without the big long switch statement, the difference being that it is multiple views I want to change the appearance of, that aren't passed to the onClick listener.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I don't have any yet. I don't know where to start

Comment: `I'm doing this by using the name of the button that was clicked to get the internal android resource ID of the sound file with the same name...` this sounds like you have code :)

Comment: That code is irrelevant to the question. I have no code for changing the appearance of  related views based on which other view was clicked.